# cin with class property

Tags: c++, oop, visual-c++

I make a class who has string property "name"

```
class Client {
private:
   string _name;
public:
   void setName(string name) {
      _name = name;
   }
   string getName() {
      return _name;
   }
   __declspec(property(put = setName, get = getName)) string name;
};
```

but in main function when I try to add it for cin it give me an error

```
int main() {
   Client client_01;
   ...
   cin >> client_01.name; // Error : No Operator Overloading
}
```

I try to declare another string to cin then use class property

```
string name;
cin >> name;
client_01.name = name;
```

Comment: Obligatory reminder that `__declspec` properties is a weird MSVC-ism. I wouldn't invest in learning a non-standard feature that only works on one OS.

Comment: `name` is private. No idea which language extension `declspec` comes from, but you should not build basic features on such extensions.

Comment: Probably because there's not a simple way to convert `cin >> client_01.name;` into an expression that actually uses `setName` or `getName`. `cin >> client_01.getName();` just wouldn't be correct, since `getName()` returns a copy. And the compiler isn't doing a transformation that be the equivalent of `cin >> someTemporary; client_01.setName(someTemporary);`

Comment: A property (as introduced by `__declspec(property)`) is not a variable; you can't use it everywhere a variable can appear, but only in limited contexts. In particular, you can't form a pointer or a reference to it; the latter is what `cin >> client_01.name` requires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of giving you an answer, here's a terrible workaround:

```cpp
string& getName() {
   return _name;
}
```

Your code should now compile, but, please, don't use it. Also I suspect this might lead to undefined behaviour.

---

As other people mentioned in the comments, this code is not compliant to standard C++ and it is very different from how this problem is typically handled. Relying on compiler specific language extensions (in this case MSVC `property`) is not ideal. Main reasons are poor documentation, support and compiler/platform dependence.

If you wanted to refactor your code in order to apply to the standard, you may:

- stick to the get-set functions;
- rename `_name` and make it public.

As regards `cin`, if you stick to the get-set paradigm, you typically use a temporary variable, like in the example you provided in your question:

```cpp
Client client_01;
// ...
string name;
cin >> name;
client_01.setName(name);
```

Whereas, if you renamed `_name` and made it public, then `cin >> client_01.name;` would work.

---

In some scenarios, overloading the `>>` operator of the whole class might be ideal instead (consider a `DateTime` class), but I don't think it suits well your case.

Comment: For `setName`, the parameter should be passed by `const` reference, so that the compiler doesn't make a copy of the string before passing.